# Density on Worldmap based on Relative Frequency

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2, geography, 2d

I'm trying to plot a 2d density on a worldmap. The problem is most of my points are around the same coordinates. My current map looks like this:

[image: map]

Code for map:

```
map = get_map(location = c(lon=43, lat=36), zoom = 6)
ggmap(map) + 
geom_density2d(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), 
data =  rel ,size = 0.3) +
stat_density2d(data = rel, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,
fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size =0.01, bins = 16,
geom = "polygon") + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)+
geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, colour = Freq),alpha = 0.75,    
size=5, data = rel)+
scale_colour_gradient(low = "#3afff4", high = "#fc0000")
```

Code for dataset:

```
rel = as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 6, ncol = 3))
rel[1,1]=1
rel[1,2]=34.55040
rel[1,3]=40.88923
rel[2,1]=0
rel[2,2]=34.16807
rel[2,3]=45.10331
rel[3,1]=0
rel[3,2]=36.02210
rel[3,3]=43.40581
rel[4,1]=0.73
rel[4,2]=36.09917
rel[4,3]=43.32750
rel[5,1]=0.94
rel[5,2]=36.35868
rel[5,3]=43.15194
rel[6,1]=1
rel[6,2]=32.12694
rel[6,3]=45.23083
colnames(rel) = c("Freq", "Latitude", "Longitude")
```

Currently the map is red where a lot of the coordinates are. Now I want the density to be red where the geom_point created red dots.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi Nico, welcome to CV. Note that your username, identicon, & a link to your user page are automatically added to every post you make, so there is no need to sign your posts. In fact, we prefer you don't. Also, on this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site ([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries.

Comment: There is an R mailing list for spatial statistics where you might find a more concentrated density of experts.